# How to treat underscores as whitespace when skipping to the next word?

Tags: cursor-movement, navigation, keyword

Let's consider an example where the cursor is at the beginning of the text `one_two three`.

- Underscores are treated as part of the word, so <kbd>w</kbd> moves right to the first letter of `three`.
- With `set iskeyword-=_` the underscore is a separate word, so <kbd>w</kbd> moves to the underscore.
- Instead, I'd like <kbd>w</kbd> to treat the underscore as whitespace, moving to the first letter of `two`.

How can I configure Vim to get the third of these behaviors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Plugins [vim-wordmotion](https://github.com/chaoren/vim-wordmotion) or [camelcasemotion](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905)

I do not know how vim can be configured to do this out of the box. There is a related wikipage: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Moving_through_camel_case_words

This wikipage points you to following plugins:

- [**vim-wordmotion**](https://github.com/chaoren/vim-wordmotion)

  > Under Vim's definition of a word:
  >
  > ```
  > CamelCaseACRONYMWords_underscore1234
  > w--------------------------------->w
  > e--------------------------------->e
  > b<---------------------------------b
  > ```
  >
  > With this plugin:
  >
  > ```
  > CamelCaseACRONYMWords_underscore1234
  > w--->w-->w----->w---->w-------->w->w
  > e-->e-->e----->e--->e--------->e-->e
  > b<---b<--b<-----b<----b<--------b<-b
  > ```
- [**camelcasemotion** (#1905)](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905), despite its name, also supports `snake_case`.
  This plugin defines new mappings `,w` `,b` and `,e`. I use `;`/`,` for repeating `fFtT` and other motions with the help of [repmo-vim](https://github.com/Houl/repmo-vim/). As always you can define your own ones, e.g. redefine the builtin ones or choose those which you think are a good pick:

  > ```
  > map w <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_w 
  > map b <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_b 
  > map e <Plug>CamelCaseMotion_e 
  > sunmap w 
  > sunmap b 
  > sunmap e
  > ```